# Talking to other people inside a bracha

Tags: tefilla, blessing, grammar-dikduk

A bracha always starts and/or ends with ברוך אתה ה'.  However, in a few selected brachos, we also talk to other people in the second person in the middle of the bracha.

Examples:

- The bracha in a cemetery:

> ‎  בָּרוּךְ אַתָּה ה' אֱלֹהֵינוּ מֶלֶךְ הָעוֹלָם אֲשֶׁר יָצַר אֶתְכֶם בַּדִּין וְדָן אֶתְכֶם בַּדִּין וְכִלְכֵּל אֶתְכֶם בְּדִין וְהֵמִית אֶתְכֶם בַּדִּין וְהוּא עָתִיד לְהָקִים אֶתְכֶם בַּדִּין לְחַיֵּי הָעוֹלָם הַבָּא בָּרוּךְ אַתָּה ה' מְחַיֵּה הַמֵּתִים: ‏

- The first bracha of Shemoneh Esrei when a ger serves as sheliach tzibbur, according to the Tanna Kamma in Bikkurim 1:4 (not accepted lehalacha):

> ברוך אתה ה' אלהינו ואלהי אבותיכם  ‏

- The occasional piyut, this is the first one I thought of but there are plenty more

> שַׁפְּרוּ מַעֲשֵׂיכֶם וּבְרִית לֹא תוּפַר. נַאֲקַתְכֶם יַאֲזִין שְׁחָקִים שִׁפַּר. וְתִיטַב לַה' מִשּׁוֹר פָּר. קָדוֹשׁ: ‏

Are there any other non-piyut examples?  And does anyone discuss the strangeness of talking to someone else in the second person while addressing Hashem?

Comment: שעשה ניסים לאבותינו, or assorted variants שעשה לך נס במקום הזה or שגמלך כל טוב

Comment: I get the variants, but how is שעשה נסים לאבותינו talking to somebody else?

Comment: שמח תשמח רעים האהובים כשמחך יצירך

Comment: @Heshy "us" ="me"+"you"

Comment: @DoubleAA or "me" + "someone else".  even a yachid says אלקינו ואלקי אבותינו

Comment: Why do you say the last one is addressing Hashem?

Comment: @shmosel it's in a bracha which is inherently addressing Hashem

Comment: Well yes, but any tefilla is addressing Hashem in that sense. The first examples are much more interesting linguistically.

Comment: That's a great question I never thought about before. My first feeling is, it's really _heimish_. It brings to the mind imagery of one brother standing up at a family reunion, and toasting and giving a speech about his beloved father. In that kind of loving, close setting, the conversation register is looser. The brother will say something like "And Dad you are so great, [turning to his brother] you remember how he saved you when... [turns back to father], so that's what I'm saying, you were always there for us". BH

Answer (score 0):

Virtually every b'rachah mixes persons – in particular, all of those that contain the words *asher kidishanu b'mitzvotav* – and the phenomenon has been explained by Rabbi Elimelech Lipman (Noam Elimelech, B'chukkotai) as follows:

> Some explain it as follows: we say 'Baruch Atah' in the second person
> and 'asher kidishanu' in the third person. This is because, at the
> start of one's work for the Creator, one has the impression that one
> is very close to God. But, persevering in one's service, one sees that
> God is in fact very distant.

See also Rashba (responsum 5:52) as follows:

> God’s existence is clear and known to all, but God's true essence is
> above and beyond any human comprehension. In order to affirm these two
> principles in our souls, [the rabbis] decided to say part [of the
> blessing] in the second person and part in the third person.

Comment: That doesn't explain why we say part of it in the second person to somebody else

Answer (score 0):

I can’t find you the quote now, but Nefesh Hachaim says that we start brachot in the second person because we acknowledge in the first half that G-d is the King of the world and is involved in our lives and that we relate to him personally.
But when we get to אשר קדשנו we switch to third person because G-d “sanctifying” and “commanding” us is infinite knowledge beyond our comprehension so therefore we use third person because we can't really speak directly to that aspect of G-d.
Brachot aren’t just to praise or thank G-d but rather also they’re meant to increase our awareness of G-d in our lives and realize He’s involved in them, but to also simultaneously realize that we can’t fully understand all aspects of G-d